# Append count value to duplicate string values as they are found

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a list of strings, let's say it looks like:

```
var reportTitleList = new List<string>(){ "January Cost Report", "January Cost Report", "January Cost Report", "February Cost Report", "March Cost Report", "April Cost Report", "April Cost Report", "May Cost Report" }
```

What I need is to be able to append (2), (3) etc to the string each time a duplicate is found. But the issue I have is that once I append a number to the first duplicate found, that won't be a duplicate anymore, so doing a LINQ search for the string value won't turn up that value and the count will be thrown off. Like for example, January Cost Report (2) will not be counted as duplicate of January Cost Report because of the (2).

I thought of using a regular expression to do it but I'm not familiar with how to use a dynamic string with those or if that's doable.

Comment: Gather all the instances and then use Linq GroupBy extension and append the counts. Alternatively use a Dictionary where the key is the name and the value is the number of instances and then use Linq Select to get your final strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var dups = reportTitleList.GroupBy(_ => _);
    var list = new List<string>();

    foreach (var element in dups)
    {
        var items = element.Select((_,index) => _+$" ({index+1})" );
        list.AddRange(items);
    }
```

Output is:

January Cost Report (1) 
January Cost Report (2) 
January Cost Report (3) 
February Cost Report (1) 
March Cost Report (1) 
April Cost Report (1) 
April Cost Report (2) 
May Cost Report (1)

Comment: Not sure this is quite what the OP is asking for. They don't want individual report titles with the count, they want each title to have whether it's the first duplicate, second duplicate etc. So the string should become January Cost Report (1), January Cost Report (2) etc.

Comment: I've amended my answer